# Is there a word to describe curiosity in a positive way?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes a curious, interested state of mind- open minded, exploring, wondering, but without being nosy.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Isn't just plain "curiosity" positive enough?

Comment: You give no less than _four_ good answers in your own question: curious, interested, open-minded, and exploring (or explorative) are all perfectly good, positive words to describe this.

Answer (score 19):

"**inquisitiveness**" and "**[inquiringness](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=HQArgkkjOCgC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=inquiringness+meaning&source=bl&ots=oeTnb10L9_&sig=UOJ6DJbLT6Rn7eOK2oglTt24yrc&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=m0FtU9-rNIay0QXDhYDYCg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q&f=false)**."

> [**inquisitive**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inquisitive): given to inquiry, research, or asking questions; eager for knowledge; intellectually curious: *an inquisitive mind*.
>
> [**inquiring**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inquiring): seeking facts, information, or knowledge: *an inquiring mind*.

Alternately, consider "**thirst**," "**craving**," "**appetency**,"**appetite**" (for learning, knowledge, etc.), and "**intellectual acquisitiveness**."

> [**acquisitiveness**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquisitive): having a strong desire to acquire things, as ideas and information: *an acquisitive mind*.

Comment: I have been around some very inquisitive kids and I am in no way saying this in a positive way.

Comment: I have never heard inquiringness used in English.  Is it a word?  Maybe... I am thinking you added it after you put my answer (interest) in a thesaurus tool.  Have you ever heard the word used in real life?

Comment: For me, there's actually a negative connotation to this word. From the Oxford dictionary online: "inquisitive: 1. Curious or inquiring: 'he was very chatty and inquisitive about everything'. 1.1 Unduly curious about the affairs of others; prying: 'I didn’t want to seem inquisitive'". Also, the word is associated with the inquisition, which definitely doesn't bring anything positive to my mind. How about pairing curiosity with an adjective, like *benevolent curiosity* or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I would also offer **interested**, since it is still very positive and has almost the same meaning as curious.

> - showing curiosity or concern about something or someone; having a feeling of interest.

Comment: I don't see the connection between *attentive* and *curious* at all. One can be attentive and curious (inquisitive), inattentive (scatterbrained) and curious, incurious and attentive (perfunctory), or incurious and inattentive (apathetic).

Comment: @ghoppe - I don't think it is far from curious.  If you are curious about something then I am sure it holds your attention.  But I don't disagree with you in that it isn't an exact match.  That is why I offered "interested" but attentive to me is a very positive word so I wanted that to be in the answer.  I am not sure how inquisitive is positive.  Maybe I am missing the boat here but curious and inquisitive are basically the same thing with the (exact) same connotation of positiveness.  Actually inquisitive seems annoying and curious seems a bit more positive.

Comment: My point, clumsily made as it was, is that you can be attentive to something without being curious about it at all. The words don't describe the same state of mind. I agree that curious and inquisitive are close synonyms. I disagree that "inquisitive" is in general, more negative. Having an "inquisitive mind" rarely has a negative connotation.

Comment: @ghoppe - I understand where you are coming from with an inquisitive mind... but I am guessing that you either haven't been around kids asking a million questions or had to teach an annoying person who wouldn't stop asking questions... Or maybe you have much more patience than I do!  I understand your point but I think there is a population that would disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "**Scientific Curiosity**".

Although this is a specific kind, it can actually be rather broad. It also doesn't have any negative connotation to it that I've noticed.

Answer (score 0):

*Intellectual curiosity* is needed for some types of investigation or inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

How about "earnest curiosity" or "genuine curiosity"

Comment: You've provided good adjectives that fit with the OP's request, but the question is asking for **a single word**. However, I realize you're not the first user to suggest adjectives, others have posted theirs too.  *sigh* :(