# Is there a term to describe inquisitiveness with a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

This is basically the opposite of [Is there a word to describe curiosity in a positive way?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169332/is-there-a-word-to-describe-curiosity-in-a-positive-way)

I'm not looking for an antonym. I'm looking for a synonym for inquisitive or curious that is more negative, like the second definition here: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inquisitive

I realize that this is a secondary definition of inquisitive itself, but in common usage the term is used in either a positive or neutral tone. The second definition is not usually inferred in written language.

The phrase might be "Asking too many questions might make you seem _____ to a potential employer". Currently I'm using "overly inquisitive" but it feels redundant based on the true second definition of inquisitive.

EDIT: The suggested duplicate is slang which is not what I'm looking for. See [a different answer to the same question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/276557/51449) which also notes the issue with "inquisitive" and the need for the redundant "overly" modifier.

Comment: @JohnFeltz thanks - that's a helpful link. See my edit? I can't really use "buttinsky" or "nosy parker" as slang would not be appropriate in this context.

Comment: 'nosy' by itself is too much of a slang term?  And just 'unprofessional' as a blanket term isn't specific enough?

Comment: "Nosy" implies that the person has no business asking the questions which is not the case here. For instance asking too many detailed questions at a job interview might not be nosy at all if the questions are about inconsequential things like the company holiday party, or if it's 20 questions about company policies, but it is "pestersome" (or any other better word). Correct "unprofessional" isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like `pester`

```
trouble or annoy (someone) with frequent or persistent requests or interruptions.
```